# phpunit fails asserting that two arrays are equal, but shows no difference

Tags: php, phpunit

Here is what phpunit says:

```
1) Asgard\Entity\Tests\EntityTest::testToArray
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     'id' => null
     'title' => 'Test Title'
     'content' => 'Test Content'
     'published' => 2015-03-04T11:19:50+0000
     'comments' => Array (
         0 => Array (
             'id' => null
             'content' => 'foo'
             'published' => 2015-03-04T11:19:50+0000
             'another_property' => null
             'news' => null
         )
         1 => Array (
             'id' => null
             'content' => 'bar'
             'published' => 2015-03-04T11:19:50+0000
             'another_property' => null
             'news' => null
         )
         2 => Array (
             'id' => null
             'content' => 'baz'
             'published' => 2015-03-04T11:19:50+0000
             'another_property' => null
             'news' => null
         )
     )
     'another_property' => null
 )
```

https://travis-ci.org/asgardphp/asgard/jobs/53029084

There is no difference between "expected" and "actual". The tests usually pass, but sometimes would fail on this.

Comment: the test fail always with php 5.6 ?

Comment: So far yes, I have only seen it failing with php 5.6

Comment: i haven't php 5.6 yet. With 5.5 and 5.3 i can't replicate your problem.

Comment: Actually just happened with 5.4: https://travis-ci.org/asgardphp/asgard/jobs/54541383

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue. Elements were not in the same order. A bit annoying though that the output doesn't show it.

I have replaced assertEquals with:

```
$this->assertTrue($this->similar_arrays($arr1, $arr2));

protected function similar_arrays($a, $b) {
    if(is_array($a) && is_array($b)) {
        if(count(array_diff(array_keys($a), array_keys($b))) > 0)
            return false;

        foreach($a as $k => $v) {
            if(!$this->similar_arrays($v, $b[$k]))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
        return $a === $b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using DateTime in your tests - Are you sure you aren't getting test that start in one second, and finish in another so there is a second difference in the timestamps depending on which stage you look at them? - Using dynamic dates and time in tests is a pretty common reason for occasional failed tests.

Comment: The datetime object is generated only once and is used both by the actual and the expected results.

And anyway, even if this was the problem, phpunit should be showing a difference betweent expected/actual.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would have wasted hours without the hint that datetimes could cause the problem. My problem was a little bit different though, I used the default convertion from laravel (Carbon), it worked after using a different format (iso8601).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have EOL in your values.

If you have a value like so:

```
'x' => 'line1
```

line2'

change it to

```
'x' => "line1\nline2"
```

Note: this may not answer direct issue the OP had, but this is what worked for me.