# PHPUnit: expect method call with array as argument

Tags: php, arrays, mocking, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test case, in which I am puzzled by the following snippet. I want to check that the method `actionUpload` calls the function exposeAndSaveDataLines correctly, i.e. that the first argument is an array as I expect it to be.

```
public function test_actionUpload()
{
    $sut = $this->getMockBuilder('MasterdataController')
                ->setMethods(array('exposeAndSaveDataLines', 'render'))
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();

    $expectedLines = require_once ($this->dataDir . 'expectedLines.php');

    $sut->expects($this->once())
        ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
        ->with($this->equalTo($expectedLines),
            $this->anything(),
            $this->anything(),
            $this->anything(),
            $this->anything());

    $sut->actionUpload();
}
```

The expected data is a printout of the current array, made with a temporary `print_r (var_export($lines))` in the actual code. I return it in the file `expectedLines.php`, and when I manually print it, it is correct.

Now, when I run the test case with a single character deliberately misspelled in `expectedLines`, I get the following error (as expected).

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
             3 => 'Colour Group Code'
-            4 => '{2F30E832-D3DB-447E-B733-7BC5125CBCCc}'
+            4 => '{2F30E832-D3DB-447E-B733-7BC5125CBCCC}'
         )
     )
 )
```

However, when I correct the mistake, it still mentions that the two arrays are not equal. However, it now prints the entire array (at least the start of it, it is a long array), but it doesn't show any differences (no - and + in front of any line). Why does the `expects` method not recognize that the two arrays are the same? How am I able to test this properly?

**EDIT 1**

I have shortened the array, such that it prints the entire array when they are not equal. Still no + or - signs in the comparison.

This is the end of my expectation PHP file.

```
    'RetTarget Area' => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => '',
            1 => '',
            2 => '{C19D52BC-834C-45DA-B17F-74D73A2EC0BB}
'
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => '1',
            1 => '1',
            2 => '{5E25C44F-C18A-4F54-B6B1-248955A82E59}'
        )
    )
);
```

This is the end of my comparison output in the console.

```
     'RetTarget Area' => Array (
         0 => Array (
             0 => ''
             1 => ''
             2 => '{C19D52BC-834C-45DA-B17F-74D73A2EC0BB}
             '
         )
         1 => Array (...)
     )
 )
```

I find it suspicious that the last Array is not fully shown in the comparison.

**EDIT 2**

I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802021/1469465) that the order of the arrays is important. I am pretty sure though I have all elements in the same order, if PHP is not doing something secret under the hood. The solution mentioned there I cannot copy, since I don't have a `$this->assertEquals` but a `->with($this->equalTo` syntax.

**EDIT 3**

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28189403/1469465) about an undocumented parameter `$canonicalize` that orders arrays before comparing. When I use it like this:

```
$sut->expects($this->once())
    ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
    ->with($this->equalTo($expectedLines, $delta = 0.0, $maxDepth = 10, $canonicalize = true, $ignoreCase = false),
        $this->anything(),
        $this->anything(),
        $this->anything(),
        $this->anything());
```

I see that the order of the arrays is indeed changed, but I still see the same error. Also, still one array is 'collapsed', which I suspect causes this failure. Besides, I don't want to order all my subarrays, they should be in the same order in the real and expected result.

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     0 => Array (
         0 => Array (
             0 => ''
             1 => ''
             2 => '{C19D52BC-834C-45DA-B17F-74D73A2EC0BB}
             '
         )
         1 => Array (...)
     )
```

**EDIT 4**

When I use `identicalTo` instead of `equalTo`, I get a more elaborate error message, saying that the one array is not identical to the other array, while printing both of them. I copy-pasted them both into a text file, and used the command diff to check for any differences, but there were none. Still, PHPUnit claims that the two arrays are not equal/identical.

**EDIT 5**

When I use `greaterThanOrEqual` or even `greaterThan` instead of `equalTo`, then the test passes. This does not happen for `lessThanOrEqual`. This implies that there *is* a difference between the two arrays.

If I manually change the expected outcome into something with a string that is alphabetically before the correct string, I can `lessThan` pass as well, but then of course `greaterThanOrEqual` fails.

**EDIT 6**

I am getting convinced that the line ending of the strings in my array are making this comparison to fail, which doesn't show up in all comparisons.

I now have the following assertion.

```
public function test_actionUpload_v10MasterdataFile()
{
    ....
    $sut->expects($this->once())
        ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($lines) {
            $expectedLines = include ($this->dataDir . 'ExpectedLines.php');
            $arrays_similar = $this->similar_arrays($lines, $expectedLines);
            PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($arrays_similar);
        }));
    $sut->actionUpload();
}

private function similar_arrays($a, $b)
{
    if(is_array($a) && is_array($b))
    {
        if(count(array_diff(array_keys($a), array_keys($b))) > 0)
        {
            print_r(array_diff(array_keys($a), array_keys($b)));
            return false;
        }

        foreach($a as $k => $v)
        {
            if(!$this->similar_arrays($v, $b[$k]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if ($a !== $b)
        {
            print_r(PHP_EOL . 'A: '. $a. PHP_EOL . 'Type: ' . gettype($a) . PHP_EOL);
            print_r(PHP_EOL . 'B: '. $b. PHP_EOL . 'Type: ' . gettype($b) . PHP_EOL);
        }
        return $a === $b;
    }
}
```

With the following result.

```
A: {72C2F175-9F50-4C9C-AF82-9E3FB875EA82}

Type: string

B: {72C2F175-9F50-4C9C-AF82-9E3FB875EA82}

Type: string
```

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include the solution that you found to make it work.  You can answer your own question with the solution that you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work, although it is a bit of a compromise. I am now removing newlines before I compare the arrays. This cannot be done in the `with` method, so I have made the following construction.

```
public function test_actionUpload_v10MasterdataFile()
{
    /*
     * Create a stub to disable the original constructor.
     * Exposing data and rendering are stubbed.
     * All other methods behave exactly the same as in the real Controller.
     */
    $sut = $this->getMockBuilder('MasterdataController')
                ->setMethods(array('exposeAndSaveDataLines', 'render'))
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();

    $sut->expects($this->once())
        ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($lines) {
            $expectedLines = include ($this->dataDir . 'ExpectedLines.php');
            PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($this->similar_arrays($lines, $expectedLines));
        }));

    // Execute the test
    $sut->actionUpload();
}

...

private function similar_arrays($a, $b)
{
    /**
     * Check if two arrays have equal keys and values associated with it, without
     * looking at order of elements, and discarding newlines.
     */
    if(is_array($a) && is_array($b))
    {
        if(count(array_diff(array_keys($a), array_keys($b))) > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach($a as $k => $v)
        {
            if(!$this->similar_arrays($v, $b[$k]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $a = rtrim($a);
        $b = rtrim($b);
        $extended_output = false;
        if ($extended_output && ($a !== $b))
        {
            print_r(PHP_EOL . 'A: '. $a. PHP_EOL . 'Type: ' . gettype($a) . PHP_EOL);
            print_r(PHP_EOL . 'B: '. $b. PHP_EOL . 'Type: ' . gettype($b) . PHP_EOL);
        }
        return $a === $b;
    }
}
```