# Did the behavior of `$this` in a scope change from PHP 5.3.29 to 5.5.24?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, this

Short question: Did the behavior of `$this` in a scope change from PHP 5.3.29 to 5.5.24? I couldn't find any relevant changes in the [PHP 5 Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php).

Details:
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136497/phpunit-expect-method-call-with-array-as-argument), I thought I had a solution for my problem (In PHPUnit, expect method call with array as argument). This was my solution

```
public function test_actionUpload_v10MasterdataFile()
{
    /*
     * Create a stub to disable the original constructor.
     * Exposing data and rendering are stubbed.
     * All other methods behave exactly the same as in the real Controller.
     */
    $sut = $this->getMockBuilder('MasterdataController')
                ->setMethods(array('exposeAndSaveDataLines', 'render'))
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();

    $sut->expects($this->once())
        ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($lines) {
            $expectedLines = include ($this->dataDir() . 'ExpectedLines.php');
            PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($this->similar_arrays($lines, $expectedLines));
        }));

    // Execute the test
    $sut->actionUpload();
}
```

It is working on my local environment (PHP 5.5.24, Zend Engine v2.5.0), but when I copy the code to our test server (PHP 5.3.29, Zend Engine v2.3.0), this does not work, due to this line:

```
$expectedLines = include ($this->dataDir() . 'ExpectedLines.php');
```

The error is:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

Could this be due to PHP version, or should I look somewhere else for the reason why it fails on one server, but not on another?

Comment: you're using `$this` inside a closure, which obviously will not inherit any variables from the calling scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you have changed scopes at that point.  I'm not sure what changed either, but your code should *not* work, at least the way PHP scope rules are defined.  Below is your code around the issue:

```
$sut->expects($this->once())
    ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function($lines) {
        $expectedLines = include ($this->dataDir() . 'ExpectedLines.php');
        PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($this->similar_arrays($lines, $expectedLines));
    }));
```

Inside the `returnCallback` function, you're still technically 'inside' the class, but you need to *import* variables from the outside scope (this behavior in PHP is different from other languages such as Javascript which do not require this).  This is how it should work:

```
$self = $this; // Not necessary after PHP 5.4 where you can just use($this)
$sut->expects($this->once())
        ->method('exposeAndSaveDataLines')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($lines) use($self) {
            $expectedLines = include ($self->dataDir() . 'ExpectedLines.php');
            PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($self->similar_arrays($lines, $expectedLines));
        }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an important difference introduced in 5.4:

> - Added closure $this support back.

Meaning, in 5.3, `$this` inside an anonymous function did not refer to anything, the surrounding context was not being preserved. 5.4 added support for this (back), so `$this` inside an anonymous function refers to the `$this` from the surrounding context. The workaround before was:

```
$_this = $this;
function () use ($_this) {
    $_this->foo();
};
```